# Rich Whip Storage Temperature

Tags: storage-lifetime

Please specify the temperature range in which rich whip is to be stored and whether it should be stored in the freezer or chiller.

Answer (score 1):

Freezer or refrigerator depends on how long you want to store it. From the [manufacturer’s website](http://www.richwhip.com/rich-whip.php):

> Rich Whip is perfect to have on-hand for any occasion. Keep frozen until ready to use, thaw and enjoy! It stays fresh in the refrigerator for up to two weeks.

The range is given by the [fda](https://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ConsumerUpdates/ucm093704.htm):

> Keep your appliances at the proper temperatures. Keep the refrigerator temperature at or below 40° F (4° C). The freezer temperature should be 0° F (-18° C). Check temperatures periodically. Appliance thermometers are the best way of knowing these temperatures and are generally inexpensive.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the pre-whipped product may be thawed and then refrozen. The ready-to-whip product, once thawed, should *not* be refrozen. If refrozen, it will not whip.